# Convert object to generic abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I got here a class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class SIBRegisterHardware2<T> : Register.IRegisterHardware<UInt16, UInt16> where T : IDevice
{
    protected T open()
    {
       // connect to server and return device T 
    }

    // ..
}

public class Device : SIBRegisterHardware2<IDevice>
{
    // ..
}
```

and some derived classes:

```
internal class DeviceA: SIBRegisterHardware2<IDeviceA>
{
}

internal class DeviceB: SIBRegisterHardware2<IDeviceB>
{
}
```

Now I am looking for a solution that allows me this:

```
if(createDevA == true) {
  Device<IDevice> devHandle = new DeviceA();
} else {
  Device<IDevice> devHandle = new DeviceB():
}
```

The thing is that code like this produces errors like that:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'DeviceA' to 'SIBRegisterHardware2<IDevice>'
```

Is there a way that would allow me to abstract a template like this?

---

Something I tried out is creating another class that works with reflection:

```
public class DeviceX : SIBRegisterHardware2<IDevice>
{
    private Register.IRegisterHardware<UInt16, UInt16> device = null;
    private Type deviceType = null;

    public DeviceX (String hwInterfaceClassName)
    {
        if (hwInterfaceClassName.Equals("DeviceA")) {

            device = new DeviceA();
            deviceType = device.GetType();
        }
        else if (hwInterfaceClassName.Equals("DeviceB")) {

            device = new DeviceB();
            deviceType = device.GetType();
        }
    }

    public override String doSomething(int param)
    {
        return (String)deviceType.GetMethod("doSomething").Invoke(device, new object[] { param }); ;
    }
}
```

but is that a neat design?

Comment: `DeviceA` and `DeviceB` aren't derived from `Device`. Moreover, `Device` isn't a generic type, and you can't write `Device<IDevice>`. Have I missed something?

Comment: thanks for the hint. i added a missing class ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the interface instead of abstract class for the `SIBRegisterHardware2` type.
And than you can use [Covariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx):

```
public interface IDevice { }

public interface IDeviceA : IDevice { }
public interface IDeviceB : IDevice { }

public interface ISIBRegisterHardware2<out T> where T : class, IDevice
{
    void DoSomething();
}

internal class DeviceA : ISIBRegisterHardware2<IDeviceA>
{
    //...
}

internal class DeviceB : ISIBRegisterHardware2<IDeviceB>
{
    //...
}

if (createDevA == true)
{
    ISIBRegisterHardware2<IDevice> devHandle = new DeviceA();
}
else
{
    ISIBRegisterHardware2<IDevice> devHandle = new DeviceB();
}
```

**UPDATE 0**

```
public interface ISIBRegisterHardware2<out T> : Register.IRegisterHardware<UInt16, UInt16> where T : class, IDevice
{
    T Open();
}

public abstract class SIBRegisterHardware2<T> : ISIBRegisterHardware2<T> where T : class, IDevice
{
    T ISIBRegisterHardware2<T>.Open()
    {
        return OpenInternal();
    }

    protected virtual T OpenInternal()
    {
        //Common logic to open.
    }
}

internal class DeviceA : SIBRegisterHardware2<IDeviceA>
{
    //...
}

internal class DeviceB : SIBRegisterHardware2<IDeviceB>
{
    //...
}

ISIBRegisterHardware2<IDevice> devHandle;
if (createDevA == true)
{
    devHandle = new DeviceA();
}
else
{
    devHandle = new DeviceB();
}
devHandle.Open();
```

Comment: The problem here is, that `ISIBRegisterHardware2` is not an `interface`. It is an `abstract class` which does implement a few methods.

Comment: What's stopping you to extract an interface from the base class and work with the interface?

Comment: There are methods that I want to implement in `ISIBRegisterHardware2` e.g. `public T open()` which connects the program to a device that is plugged to the computer. Every device does this the same way. The only difference of course is the device type that is returned (generic).

Comment: That's ok too - just do what you are saying and implement the interface signature i.e: T Open(); and add this in the ISIBRegisterHardware2 interface (unless I missed something here)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then I'd had to implement `open()` for each device. But I want `ISIBRegisterHardware2` to provide an implementation to all subclasses. If `ISIBRegisterHardware2` is an `interface` instead of an `abstract class` I cannot implement `open()` since an `interface` doesn't allow concrete implementations.

Comment: And this `ISIBRegisterHardware2<IDevice> devHandle = new DeviceA();` would work then?

Comment: Okay :D I'll try this out and let you know!